# Can search engines read the links generated by an external javascript link?

Tags: javascript

I have posted an unclear question before which was voted to be closed and deleted.
I am sorry but being a newb I did not know how to ask so I have decided to give it another try with a documented question.

**Please wait a few minutes before voting down the question, I really need an answer. If you comment that the question is stupid I will close it.**

In my header.php I load a javascript code which loads a couple of links from an EXTERNAL SITE onto my site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    el="http://EXTERNALSITE.com/sc/out.php?s=MYSITESID"
    sl=new Array();  
    sh=new Array();  
    st=new Array();  
    thpm=new Array();  

    sn=new Array(); 
    ns=new Array();  
    sd=new Array();  
    th=new Array();  

    a="</a>";  
    af="<a target='_blank'";  
    ps="<img border='0' src=thumbs/";  


    function dw(n) {  
        document.write(n,"\n");  
    }

    function showLink(n,s,b){
        if (!s){
            s='anc'
        } 

        if (!b){b=''}  
        else {b="&b="+b}  

        ast = af + " class='" + s + "' href='" + el;  
        n=n-1; 

        if (sl[n]&&sl[n]!=""){  
            dw(ast+"&o="+sl[n]+b+"'>"+sn[n]+a)  
        }  
        else{
            dw(ast+b+"'>"+et+a)  
        } 
    }  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://EXTERNALSITE.COM/js/MYSITEDID.js"></script>
```

Here is the code I use to display the links:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> showLink(1)</script>
```

**The question is, can search engines read the links generated by this script?**

After the page has loaded, I have this in my source code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">  
    showLink(4);
</script>

<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" class="anc" href="http://EXTERNALSITE.COM/sc/out.php?s=MYSITEID&amp;o=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thelink.com">  
    The Link  
</a>
```

Comment: There's no way anybody can tell you what all search engines can or will do.

Comment: If you didn't post your code in a garbled mess, your post would be less likely to be down voted.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat: that was excatly the reason of my edit of the OP post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [Google can do this](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4159807.htm) although there are no guarantees as to how dynamically generated links will be treated with regard to conferring pagerank